# Javascript onblur event alert box does not go away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, onblur

I am using a blur event to fire a JS alert. If I click in the input box where I am calling the event and then without entering anything I click on new tab button on browser or change tab etc, the alert gets triggered because of blur effect on the input box. But the alert refuses to go away even if OK is clicked. However, this does not happen if I am click anywhere inside the same page or browser tab. Then, clicking the OK button closes the alert box. The need to click on a new tab etc is because a user may need to copy data from somewhere else to paste in the input box

The HTML

```
<input pattern=".{10,}" type='text' id='phone' name="Phone"  maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone" <?php if(isset($_POST['Phone'])){echo "Value ='$_POST[Phone]'";}?> required>
```

JS

```
$('#phone').blur(function(){checkValue($(this).val());});

function checkValue(phval) {
    var res = phval.substr(0, 1);
    if (res!=="7" && res!=="8" && res!=="9" ) {
        alert("Number has to be Mobile number starting with 7, 8 or 9 / Your Value is "+phval);
    }
}
```

It seems to be some simple issue. But I can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: Hah, now that's a curious issue...

Comment: *"I am using a blur event to fire a JS alert."* Don't. It **will** cause you problems, because `alert` (and its cousins `prompt` and `confirm`) as remnants of an archaic past and don't play by the modern rules. (blur isn't as bad as focus, which can get you stuck in an infinite loop, but...) Instead of an alert, use an on-page mechanism (such as a "modal"-like `div`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am not very familiar with the "modal" like div concept. Could you expand a little bit on that ?

Comment: @user3526204: Just search, there are dozens of examples here on SO and plenty of jQuery plugins to do it (such as jQuery UI's Dialog).

Comment: Sure ...thanks..let me give it a go.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a work around than an answer, which I have created to solve my issue inspired by T.J.Crowder's suggestion to use  "Modal" like div.

I have created a fade in error div on blur event rather than an alert. And then fade it away by click. Almost behaving like the JS alert box. Only thing is that it does not freeze all activity on the page on alert/pop up.

html

```
<input pattern=".{10,}" type='text' id='phone' name="Phone"  maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone" <?php if(isset($_POST['Phone'])){echo "Value ='$_POST[Phone]'";}?> required>

<div id="pop">
    <div class="errormsg">Mobile Number has to start with 7,8, or 9 !</div>
<br>
    <div id="popclose">OK</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#pop{
    display:none
}

#pop{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:40%;
    width:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:maroon;
    border:5px solid yellow;
    color:white
 }

#popclose{
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:yellow
}

.errormsg{
     font-weight:bold
}
```

JS

```
function checkValue(phval) {

$('#phone').blur(function(){checkValue($(this).val());return true;});
    var res = phval.substr(0, 1);
    if (res!=="7" && res!=="8" && res!=="9" ) {
//       alert("Number has to be Mobile number starting with 7, 8 or 9 / Your Value is "+phval);
            $('#pop').fadeIn('fast');

    }

}

$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#popclose').click(function(){
       $('#pop').fadeOut('fast');   
    });
});
```

Thank you T J Crowder